# Is it possible to create the following simulation in mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, syntax, simulation

Consider a set of discrete "states" $|1\rangle,|2\rangle,|3\rangle,\dots,|N_{\text{max}}\rangle$). Next, assume that there are 1000 "particles" occupying the state 1 at the initial moment of "time". Let us discretize the time on timesteps $\Delta t$. There is a probability $P$ for each particle occupying the state $|N\rangle$ to go to the state $|N+1\rangle$ at the step $\Delta t$. When each such transition happens, the number of particles at the state $|N+1\rangle$ is increased by $1+\Delta n$ (possibly not integer).

I would like Mathematica to simulate this process and return a table

`{Timestep, Total number of particles, Number of particles at level 1 *E0 + Number of particles at level 2 *E0/2+...}`,

where E0 is some constant. It is possible?

The physical system I want to model is an injection of high energy particles into the thermal bath and the evolution of such particles due to energy loss (which defines $P$), population increase due to knocking out thermal particles and population decrease due to "annihilation" (defining $\Delta n$). The levels correspond to the values of energy, with $|1\rangle$ being the level with the energy $E_{0}$ and each next level corresponds to twice smaller energy (on average the high energy particle scattering on a low energy particle lose an energy $\Delta E = E/2$).

P.S. Unfortunately I am completely unfamiliar with making simulations in Mathematica.

Comment: How come that you are completely unfamiliar if your reputation here is so high? :)

Comment: @yarchik : so far I have used Mathematica in questions not related to simulations only.

Comment: @yarchik : I even don't know what I should start with.

Comment: First you need to figure out what probability distribution determines P. Then use RandomVariate to generate a set of probabilities.Use these to construct an evolution over time (delta t is probably a post hoc consideration that can be ignored for the also) Finally do statistics on the set of evolutions. I will try to do a bit of code for this but am busy dealing with WFH and coronapocalypse so it might take me a few days and in that time somebody else will have constructed a better one. :)

Comment: @yarchik : I've added a description.

Comment: Check out [DiscreteMarkovProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html).

Comment: @ChrisK : it seems that it does not allow simulating an increase in the number of particles in each transition in an adequate way.

Comment: @JohnTaylor I see, it's more complicated than I thought.  If you're not interested in the stochastic aspect, this seems identical to a matrix population model, which is well understood (see e.g. [Caswell 2006](https://www.whoi.edu/cms/files/mpm2e_tableofcontents_116984.pdf)).  If you could specify the $\Delta n$, I might be able to help more.

Comment: @MikeColacino : my problem is that I am not familiar with the relevant syntax.

Comment: I'm not a physicist but I don't understand how the added number of particles could possibly be a non-integer.  Is there another part of the process in which a particle that transitions to the next level becomes more than one particle?  Maybe the number of additional particles (for each particle that transitions) follows a Poisson distribution?

Comment: @JimB : 1) the value of $\Delta n$ is given by the average change of the number of particles. So for the given particle interaction, it is always -1, 0 or 1, for example. But probabilities to get these different changes are different, which results in non-integer $\Delta n$ on average. The obtained value, $\Delta n$, may be set as a constant.

Comment: Since I'm more that pretty ignorant about this, I'll just try one more question.  It appears that with a single probability $p$ a particle can stay in the same state or move to the next state.  So where does the -1 come from?  (Again, I'll stop after this.)

Comment: @JimB : in the physical system I consider, it corresponds to the disappearance in the annihilation process when colliding the anti-particle from the background population.